# convert map<string, int> to void* and back and get keys

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, void-pointers

I am trying to cast a map pointer to `void *` with `reinterpret_cast` and then cast it back using `static_cast`

Right now i have a problem trying to get the values stored in the map after casting the `void *` back to `map<string, int> *`

I tried with both a range based loop and with an iterator but i can't seem to find a way to get the keys, every time i try to access the map values i get a segmentation fault.

This is a small example of the code i have:

```
auto *map_pointer = new map<string, int>;

for (const auto &entry : array){
    if (map_pointer->find(entry) == map_pointer->end()) {
        map_pointer->at(entry) = 1;
    } else {
        map_pointer->at(entry)++;
    }
}

void *test = reinterpret_cast<void *>(map_pointer);
auto foo = static_cast<std::map<std::string, int> *>(test);
```

I need to find a way, if possible, to retrieve the keys of the map to get the values back from it.
Right now i don't know if the problem leading to the segmentation fault is in the casting to `void *` and back or the error occurs when i was trying to get the keys back with the iterator or the loop.

Comment: `void *test = map_pointer;` - That's it. No need to pull out the hydrogen bomb of casts for something so basic

Comment: @StoryTeller something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1d5c5789d1bfa35) ?

Comment: @pergy - Very much like this. And good on you for avoiding the superfluous dynamic allocation as well. Didn't mention it, to stay on topic.

Comment: I'd argue that the hydrogen bomb of casting is the C-style cast; reinterpret cast is only an atomic bomb (it is very slightly safer)

Comment: On a side note, your use of `find()` is redundant, and your use of `at()` when `find()` returns `end()` is erroneous (throws an exception), you would need to use `insert()` instead. You can simplify the loop by using `operator[]` to perform the find+insert logic for you: `for (const auto &entry : array){ *(map_pointer)[entry]++; }`

Comment: The code you have shown us is fine - so it's something to do with the code you *haven't* show.  We need a [mcve] please.

Comment: @Yakk - There *are* casts a reinterpret_cast won't be obliged to do. A c-style cast will hapilly level entire cities. It's a nuke in my book.

Comment: @MartinBonner the code i've shown it's pretty much exactly the code i have, the only thing not present is the process of how to get the keys and corresponding values because i can't figure out how to do that

Comment: @StoryTeller i need that because that code it's inside a function and i need to new to keep the map pointer valid after the return (i return the pointer)

Comment: @JohnSmith - Return by value. RVO and move semantics are a thing. Don't do premature optimization.

Comment: @RemyLebeau with your code i get an error on ```[entry]``` saying ```Array index is not integer```

Comment: @StoryTeller obviously i'm returning a void pointer because the specifications i'm given only allow me to do so otherwise i would've returned by value... usually i'm a masochist when it comes to code but not that much

Comment: *"obviously i'm returning a void pointer because the specifications i'm given only allow me to do so otherwise"* - It's not obvious at all. And your previous comment indicated you had another reason. But whatever, constraints are constraints.

Comment: @StoryTellersorry didn't want to sound rude, it's just that i've been bashing my head at this problem for the past 4 hours

Comment: @JohnSmith make sure you are dereferencing the `map*` pointer before you invoke `operator[]` on the `map` object. Try using `(*map_pointer)[entry]++` instead. `std::map::operator[]` adds an element if it does not already exist. `std::map::at()` throws an exception if you request an element that does not exist.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks that was the problem,  i thought ```at``` worked like ```[]``` in the sense that it would add the element if it didn't already exist

Comment: @JohnSmith: Nope. Read the [`at()` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at): "*If no such element exists, an exception of type `std::out_of_range` is thrown.*" Compared to the [`operator[]` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at): "*..., performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Regarding the pointer cast - as StoryTeller pointed out - you can just assign the map pointer to a `void*` and `static_cast` back when you need it.
- Regarding the segfault, you call `at` for a key not found in the map, which results in `std::out_of_range`

Your corrected code could be something like the following:

```cpp
std::map<int, int> m = {{0, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 32}};
std::vector<int> arr = {0, 3, 2};

for (const auto &entry : arr){
    if (m.find(entry) == m.end()) {
        m.insert({entry, 1});
    } else {
        m[entry]++;
    }
}    

void *mp = &m;    
std::map<int, int> *m2 = static_cast<std::map<int, int>*>(mp);

for (const auto& i : *m2) {
    std::cout << i.first << ":" << i.second << "\n";
}
```

printing `0:9 1:9 2:33 3:1`. See [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f48e0f5e0c4870b)

Comment: The problem was in the use of the ```at```, i thought it would access the value with key ```entry``` like the ```operator[]``` if ```entry``` was at ```m.end``` and set it like ```operator[]``` does but apparently it throws

Comment: Yes, `[ ]` is "retrieve-or-create" operation but `at` throws if doesn't find key

Answer (score 2):

My rule of thumbs are:

- When you cast with `static_cast`, cast back with `static_cast`
- When you cast with `reinterpret_cast`, cast back with `reinterpret_cast`
- If you plan to cast a value and then use the casted value, do **not** use `reinterpret_cast`
- Using a C or ctor-style cast is acceptable when the conversion is a well-known/trivial one such as `std::string{"Hello, world"}`

Applied here, I'd say "use reinterpret_cast both ways".

Answer (score 1):

To avoid an exception being thrown when the entry is not present, the correct loop code is this:

```
for (const auto &entry : array){
    ++(*map_pointer)[entry];
}
```

Are you sure you're not just seeing an unhandled exception resulting in an `abort()`?

Comment: if i don't try to find the entries the program returns 0 (end of main), the segmentation fault (exit code 11) is present only when i try to retrieve the map values

Comment: @JohnSmith `at` requires that the entry exists in the map. `operator[]` will create it with a default value if it does not.